# If I Install Windows from from USB, will Ubuntu be removed from my harddrive completely?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, windows-10, usb, installation

I need Ubuntu gone from my harddrive, is it possible that if I install Windows from USB that Ubuntu will be gone and Windows will just overwrite and replace it?

Comment: if you install Windows, on the same partition as Ubuntu, then it indeed will be removed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "wipe" your disk (it doesn't REALLY wipe everything, unless you use `clean all` instead, but it destroys the partition table and so):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Type `exit` again to leave the command prompt. Then `Turn off your PC` and boot again to start the installation.

Or you can delete the unwanted partition one by one:

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do I use the "clean all"? I want to actually wipe the disk and take everything off before reinstalling windows.

Comment: You type `clean all` instead of `clean`. But you don't really wanna use it since it will zero-fill the whole drive so it take a LOOOONG time. It's not really necessary anyway (unless you are some computer clean freak)

Comment: Will I be able to reinstall Windows on it after though?

Comment: Why will you not be? (Unless your HDD coincidentally died during the filling process...)

Comment: So after I do a clean all and everything on my SSD (it's not an HDD) is wiped, I can plug in my Windows USB and install it fine?

Comment: Sure. If it's an SSD you don't wanna use `clean all`, since zero-filling makes even less sense on it (and it might hurt if its firmware is silly)

Comment: So for the SSD what should I do instead of clean all?

Comment: As I always suggested, `clean` is what you need, no matter it's HDD or SSD

Comment: So say I have a 512GB SSD with Ubuntu on it (pretend that that's taking 115GB up, so the SSD has 397 GB), and I need to wipe the SSD. So I do clean. This will wipe the SSD and revert the drive back to 512GB correct?

Answer (score 0):

When installing windows, instead of upgrading, choose custom install, this will wipe your HDD of ubuntu

This is a step by step guide, all you do is instead of choosing "Upgrade" you choose "Custom"
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ie/windows/installing-reinstalling-windows#1TC=windows-7

Read the question completely wrong the first time, apologies.

Comment: I need it to overwrite Ubuntu! How do I install it to the Ubuntu partition to overwrite it? @RyanIG

Comment: @TraceBroyles Edited the answer for you.

Comment: @TraceBroyles - Delete the partition Ubuntu is installed on using a tool like [gparted](http://gparted.org/)